# Efficiently changing values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

my goal is to update one column's values to np.nan where a second column has a certain value. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
    c1    c2
a    1    8
b    2    8
c    3    8
d    4    8
e   32    8
f   32    8
g    2    8
```

should become

```
    c1    c2
a    1    8
b    2    8
c    3    8
d    4    8
e   32    nan
f   32    nan
g    2    8
```

The solution I have based on reading this and other sites is the following monstrosity:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1':[1,2,3,4,32,32,2], 'c2':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8]}, index=list('abcdefg'))
df.iloc[[df.index.get_loc(x) for x in df.loc[df['c1'] == 32].index.values],df.columns.get_loc(('c2'))] = np.nan
```

There must be a proper way to do this that doesn't involve list comprehension, right? Everything 'natural' that I tried resulted in me setting a value on a copy. Thanks so much.

Comment: `df.loc[df['c1'].eq(32), 'c2'] = np.nan`

Comment: If you have a SettingWithCopyWarning, this means you did something wrong prior to this code

Comment: Also, not this is just a warning, not an error.  Many of the times this is warning of you of behavior that you didn't desire anyway.

Comment: For some reason on the example data frame it works fine. On my actual code it still raises a warning about the copy thing :/ Hopefully I can figure out why.

Comment: Just for posterity, but the reason I was still getting the error in my actual code was due to some columns being int32 and some float64. Casting all to float64 removed the warning.